# Wrong URL on language selection with langhandler

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

On Yii 1.x

We found it quite difficult to implement a language selection option with Yii, so, we are using the following extension:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/langhandler/

Like so:

*main.php URL Manager:*

```
urlManager'=>array(
                    'class'=>'application.extensions.langhandler.ELangCUrlManager',
                    'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'rules'=>array(
                      '<lang:(pt|en)>/<_c>/<_a>/' => '<_c>/<_a>',

            ),
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'rules'=>array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
                        ),
```

When we click "en", instead of getting:
http://blabla.dev/experience/info/114?lang=en

We are getting:
http://blabla.dev/experience/info?lang=en

So the ID part of this url is being completely ignored.

Can anyone give us a hand here?

We have tried to change the rules to:
   `'<lang:(pt|en)>/<_c>/<_a>/<_i>/' => '<_c>/<_a>',`

and a lot of other combinations, but that is just guessing.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same problem =[